# function with a parameter to reverse loop

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, photoshop-script

In JavaScript is there any way to pass a parameter into a function so it reverses the direction of the loop?

```
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;
var str = "";

// iterateLayers(srcDoc, true); // 3 2 1 0
iterateLayers(srcDoc, false);  // 0 1 2 3

function iterateLayers(srcDoc, rev)
{
  var numOfLayers = sauce.layers.length;
  if (rev)
  {
    for (var i = numOfLayers -1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      str+= i + " ";
    }
  }
  else
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < numOfLayers; i++)
    {
      str+= i + " ";
    }
  }
}

alert(str);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HA! I figured it out with ternary operators. Go me!

```
// call the source document
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;

var str = "";

// iterateLayers(srcDoc, true); // 3 2 1 0
iterateLayers(srcDoc, false);  // 0 1 2 3

function iterateLayers(sauce, rev)
{
  var numOfLayers = sauce.layers.length;
  for (var i = numOfLayers -1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    var index = (rev == true) ?  i : (sauce.layers.length-i)-1;
    str+= index + " ";
  }
}

alert(str);
```

Comment: You could simplify a bit.  Change `(rev == true)` to `rev`.

Comment: `(rev == true)` is the same as `(rev)` in this case. Most coders use the latter, I find it easier to "read" back with the former.  But thanks for the tip